# How to use a variable to define the size of an array (matrix) in C?

Tags: c

I have just started learning C (I have very basic JS knowledge) and I am trying to create an array that will hold an "X" number of values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

// Instead of doing this:

float numGrades[4][4] = {}

return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int numStudents = 4;
int numGrades = 4;

/*

This does not work:
float numGrades[numStudents][numGrades] = {};


This does not work either:
float numGrades["%i", numStudents]["%i", numGrades] = {};

*/
```

Comment: Both of those are totally bogus. Probably what you _wanted_ was `float grades[students][grades] = {};` but that still has an issue because you're redefining the variable `grades`. You need to call it something else. Consider `num_students` and `num_grades`.

Comment: If you are trying to learn C by trial and error, and/or by watching random youtube tutorials and the like, do know that this is not a good way to learn. Get yourself a proper textbook and work your way through it.

Comment: @paddy Sorry, I used the wrong name for the variable that will hold the array. But even if I have a different name for it, I still cannot create an array based on the integer assigned to those variables

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76700521/1553090). You have two problems. It's unclear why you are defining your arrays with a different syntax, when it's clear from the first example you already know what an array definition looks like.

Comment: @paddy You were right, when I declared the second time, the influence of JS made me use the extra "=". Still, when I use the variable "num_students", i still get an error l when I try to use it as the size of the array

Comment: Error messages are important. Read them. Do not say "I get an error" and expect anybody to tell you how to fix it, if you don't show the error message. My crystal ball says you might be using a C++ compiler, in which case the array sizes must be declared `const`, noting that VLAs (variable-length arrays) are compiler extensions and not actually supported in C++. Your recent question edits show the same problem. You are redefining `numGrades`. If you keep editing the question and changing the code, it impacts the correctness of all the existing answers and comments.

Comment: Hint: learn the difference between an array and a *Variable Length Array* (VLA) and whether there is one that can be initialized and one that can't...

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters pointed out, you're trying to redefine one of your variables as something else. Variables need to have unique names (within a scope. If you don't know what that means, then just stick to 'variables need unique name'). Also as the commenters pointed out, variable names should be as descriptive as possible. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num_students = 4;
    int num_grades = 4;
    float student_grades[num_students][num_grades];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j) {
            student_grades[i][j] = 3.14;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_grades; ++j) {
            printf(" %f", student_grades[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not support the empty braces initializer notation unless you’re using C23 or compiler extensions.  C does not support initialization of VLAs, though it’s conceivable that some compilers do as an extension, but the definition of an initializer for a VLA is fraught (which is why it isn’t supported).  A default initializer such as empty braces is about all that makes sense.

Comment: This is true. Copy and paste "error" from the question... Given that I explicitly initialise the array, I shall edit my answer to make it more correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both your attempts are doing the same thing, and both are invalid. You are trying to define a single `float` variable, and using an invalid expression to initialize it. You also cannot redefine the variable `grades`.

You're doing this:

```
int students = 4;
int grades = 4;
float grades = [students][grades] = {};
```

The compiler should tell you something like the following:

```
error: conflicting types for 'grades'; have 'float'
     float grades = [students][grades] = {};
           ^~~~~~

note: previous definition of 'grades' with type 'int'
     int grades = 4;
         ^~~~~~

error: expected expression before '[' token
     float grades = [students][grades] = {};
                    ^
```

By choosing different names for your dimensions and the array, and by fixing the definition (removing the bogus extra `=`), the problem is fixed.

```
int num_students = 4;
int num_grades = 4;
float grades[num_students][num_grades] = {};
```

Comment: Note: [Empty initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) a [VLA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) is a [C23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23) feature.

Answer (score -4):

```
int main() {
    int numStudents = 4;
    int numGrades = 4;
    float numGrades[sizeof(numStudents)][sizeof(numGrades)] = {};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just use sizeof( var )

Comment: you shouldnt be using sizeof operator at all here